# asymptotic notation rearrangment

Tags: combinatorics, asymptotics

I'm having a look at this paper http://arxiv-web3.library.cornell.edu/pdf/0903.3048v1.pdf namely Theorem 5 and why it implies Theorem 2 immediately.

Basically, I'm hoping somebody could explain to me, why, for $k$ large, that if  $k \le m^{\frac{1+\log_{2} m}{2}}(1+o(1))$, then this immediately implies that $m \ge 2^{\sqrt{2\log_{2} k}(1+o(1))}$.

I can't seem to rearrange this as it gets far too messy. Any help hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Without going into too much detail:

Taking logs,
$$ \log_2k\le\frac{1+\log_2m}{2}\log_2m+\underbrace{\log_2(1+o(1))}_{o(1)}\le\frac{(\log_2m) ^2}{2}(1+o(1))$$
(the latter estimate is quite rough).
From this
$$(\log_2m) ^2\ge2\log_2k(1+o(1)).$$
Take the square root and exponentiate, and you're done.
(The final $o(1)$ term will be negative, so it could seem more natural to write $(1-o(1))$ on the right.)

Comment: Many thanks. I am still a little confused here though. What if we take the ceiling function? In other words, replace log(m) with $\lceil log_{2}m \rceil$?

I'm not asking you to read through the paper for me, but am wondering whether or not this is a concern because obviously log(m) needs to be an integer?

Comment: does it boil to whether or not $m^{1-o(1)}(1+o(1)) = 1+o(1)$? Which is clearly not true so doesn't it kinda go wrong here?

Comment: First, if $k$ is large then $m$ must be large too, so whether you take the ceiling function on its log should be of no concern (in the sense that $\lceil\log_2m\rceil=(\log_2m)(1+o(1))$). I don't understand why think that $\log m$ “obviously” needs to be an integer. And to your second question: No, I don't see how that is relevant. As I am confused about what part of my answer you don't get, I find it hard to be more specific.